# plotting a two column data frame with date

Tags: r

I'm having trouble puting this little data.frame into a plot. I use the plot() fx but it just gives me back a plot which X axis is not the date in the first column.

```
> DDDhabd
      Mes DDD.1000hab.día
1  Ene-14      0.03564701
2  Feb-14      0.03959695
3  Mar-14      0.04677090
4  Abr-14      0.04928782
5  May-14      0.03783808
6  Jun-14      0.04939231
7  Jul-14      0.05464189
8  Ago-14      0.05208003
9  Set-14      0.05475650
10 Oct-14      0.05290589
11 Nov-14      0.05714252
12 Dic-14      0.05056313
13 Ene-15      0.05688352
14 Feb-15      0.05710022
15 Mar-15      0.05754084
16 Abr-15      0.04362755
17 May-15      0.06209153
18 Jun-15      0.05715994
19 Jul-15      0.04373711
20 Ago-15      0.02462424
21 Set-15      0.03812404
22 Oct-15      0.08368198
23 Nov-15      0.07506378
24 Dic-15      0.05974877
```

I would really appreciate if you could give me a hint about where is my mistake.
Thanks

Comment: it's a good idea to paste the result of `dput(DDDhabd)` rather than what's printed in the console. So that we could probably realize that `$Mes` is not a `?Date` but a factor/character.

Comment: It's pretty clear those are either character values or factors, so the plot method for Date-classes variables will not be used. Convert to real Dates.

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking that I should turn that column into dates with as.Date, I'm trying with `as.Date(DDDhabd$Mes,format="%b%y")` but it gives me just a lot of NA NA NA.
how can I turn that column into dates?
Thank you